# Create tree structure from current child id PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a database table in mySQL like this and want create tree results with current value child.

```
id          item_id         secondary_id
1           1               1
2           1               1
3           1               1
4           1               3
5           1               3
6           1               3
7           1               3
8           1               3
9           1               3
10          1               3
11          1               3
12          1               1
13          1               1
14          1               1
15          1               1
16          1               7
17          1               7
18          1               7
19          1               7
20          1               7
```

I want get final result like this:

`$current_value = 18;`

- -> Root with `id = 1`
- ---> Reply with `id = 2`
- ---> Reply with `id = 3`
- -----> Reply with `id = 6`
- -----> Reply with `id = 7`
- -------> Reply with `id = 16`
- -------> Reply with `id = 17`
- -------> Reply with `id = 18` <-- this target `$current_value`
- -------> Reply with `id = 19`
- -------> Reply with `id = 20`
- -----> Reply with `id = 8`
- -----> Reply with `id = 9`
- ---> Reply with `id = 12`
- ---> Reply with `id = 13`

I use this SQL query, but only get result current target, previous value and next value from target.

```
$query = "(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_name
        WHERE id < $current_target
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS comment

    ORDER BY comment.id ASC
)

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_name
        WHERE id = $current_target
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS comment

    ORDER BY comment.id ASC
)

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_name
        WHERE id > $current_target
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 2
    ) AS comment

    ORDER BY comment.id
)";
```

I want get result up to Root.

Comment: Anyone can help?